# Apache2 rewrite - conditional

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` file in my project's web root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /repos/eamorr.co.uk/react_www/index.html [L,QSA]
```

The above works.

When I navigate to:

http://localhost/repos/eamorr.co.uk/react_www

I see my homepage.

And when I navigate to:

http://localhost/repos/eamorr.co.uk/react_www/contact-us

I see the "contact-us" route of my homepage (my webpage is written in React).

OK. Great.

**Now**, some users are on Linux:

When they checkout the code, they see the site at a slightly different url:

http://localhost/_eamorr/develop/eamorr.co.uk/react_www/

and

http://localhost/_eamorr/develop/eamorr.co.uk/react_www/contact-us

Regarding this line of the `.htaccess` file:

`RewriteRule . /repos/eamorr.co.uk/react_www/index.html [L,QSA]`

Instead of `.` is there some conditional that I can put in to serve index.html from a different path?

e.g.

`RewriteRule {{condition1???}} /repos/eamorr.co.uk/react_www/index.html [L,QSA]`

or (different condition = different path):

`RewriteRule {{condition1???}} /_eamorr/develop/eamorr.co.uk/react_www/index.html [L,QSA]`

I'm afraid my Apache knowledge isn't up-to-speed to do this quickly and I've spent hours at this!

=================

*Solution:*

Use a cascading htaccess rewrite rule setup as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /


#Linux localhost:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*repos/eamorr.co.uk/react_www.*$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.?[^/])*$ /repos/eamorr.co.uk/react_www/index.html [L,QSA]


#Mac localhost:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*_eamorr/eamorr.co.uk/react_www.*$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.?[^/])*$ /_eamorr/eamorr.co.uk/react_www/index.html [L,QSA]


#develop .co.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*gitWebFlow/eamorr.co.uk/develop/react_www.*$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.?[^/])*$ /gitWebFlow/eamorr.co.uk/develop/react_www/index.html [L,QSA]


#master .co.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*gitWebFlow/eamorr.co.uk/master/react_www.*$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.?[^/])*$ /gitWebFlow/eamorr.co.uk/master/react_www/index.html [L,QSA]


#default
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L,QSA]
```

This is good enough for my needs right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `react_www` is your project's root, and you're not referencing assets above that directory (publicly, via URLs), that's where the `.htaccess` should be. Then it would become

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . index.html [END]
```

You shouldn't need `RewriteBase` since you're not doing server-side external redirects, and just want virtual URLs below that directory to all serve the same file.

Comment: Hello, this was a very useful post. I updated my original question accordingly...

Comment: I'm glad it was useful, but your rules kind of defeat the purpose of moving the htaccess to what appears to be the web root. Are those sites serving anything out of directories above `react_www`? If not, you should consider moving your `DocumentRoot` or using a symlink so your repo structure doesn't have to be within a publicly accessible folder. The point is it's probably possibly for you to be using the same (tracked) file to manage each branch.